# Opencart Admin View Product SKU Filters

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Working to show SKU column and SKU filter option in admin view of Opencart 2.0.2.0 Version. I am updating `/admin/controller/catalog/product.php` but its not showing any updates. The product list comes even after commenting total code of `/admin/controller/catalog/product.php` file. Some one tell me whether I'm working on the right file or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCart make cache or modification files in `system/modification` if you're doing changes directally on files then you've to go extension->modification and then press refresh button to load your changes on frontend.

Comment: Hi Nipun, you are awesome. Yes, its storing files in `system/modification`. I refreshed modifications in the front end and it gave me the expected results. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: It is a multi store and whenever I'm refreshing at system/modification, one or two sites are going blank :( So, I restored the backup and this issue is not letting me to go with SKU filters. I have to update product.php of controller and model, product-list.php of view. Let me know if you have any idea regarding this issue.

Comment: I don't think that it could be happen that another store will goes blank, what kind of backup you're uploading to make it working, Files or database?

Comment: I am trying to update only 3 files under Model, Controller and View of admin folder. I can see them under `system/modification/admin/` folder as well.

Comment: As you said that you've to upload backup to run the stores which goes blank after refresh modificatons from admin, so my question was that what backup you're uploading files or db ?

Comment: I am uploading the files not db